# Complex UI structure and backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, backbone.js

I'm not able to wrap my head around templating a complex UI. It all makes perfect sense when following (the almost canonical) [todo mvc example](http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/), but my challenge is how to tame a UI where the elements of the `model` may be strewn all over the page?

Please consider the image below, the aha moment is just proving elusive:
[image]

A template encapsulating this would be huge and unwieldy. What is the correct way to tackle such a challenge?

Comment: Why vote to close? I'm struggling over this for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer.  One view to hold multiple sub-views with whom you should share the model(s).
As you can see here in one of my backbone project, each red rectangle is a distinct view.

[image: Backbone multiples views]

Comment: Can I please ask which templating engine you are using?

Comment: I'm using underscore.